# element from vector JAVA

Tags: java, object, vector

Suppose I have a vector my_vector, where I have 1 element of type Point

`Vector my_vector = new Vector();
 my_vector.addElement(Point(0, 0, 0))`

And I have 1 variable of type Point

`Point cur_point = new Point(0, 0, 0)`

And I want to assign this variable to the first element of "my_vector". When I write

`cur_point = my_vector.elementAt(0)`

I have an error:

`Incompatible types:
 Required: ClassName.Point
 Found: java.lang.Object`

What should I do to have a vector of Point and have a possibility to take some element from it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Use generics or type casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parameterize your `Vector`:

```
Vector<Point> my_vector = new Vector<Point>()
```

Alternatively you can cast the `Object` to a `Point`, but this is not as safe:

```
cur_point = (Point)my_vector.elementAt(0)
```

You should probably use an `ArrayList` instead of a `Vector`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) for more info.